# setting null values in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

how do I null certain values in numpy array based on a condition? 
I don't understand why I end up with 0 instead of null or empty values where the condition is not met...  b is a numpy array populated with 0 and 1 values, c is another fully populated numpy array. All arrays are 71x71x166

```
a = np.empty(((71,71,166)))
d = np.empty(((71,71,166)))
for indexes, value in np.ndenumerate(b):
    i,j,k = indexes
    a[i,j,k] = np.where(b[i,j,k] == 1, c[i,j,k], d[i,j,k])
```

I want to end up with an array which only has values where the condition is met and is empty everywhere else but with out changing its shape

FULL ISSUE FOR CLARIFICATION as asked for:
I start with a float populated array with shape (71,71,166)
I make an int array based on a cutoff applied to the float array basically creating a number of bins, roughly marking out 10 areas within the array with 0 values in between
What I want to end up with is an array with shape (71,71,166) which has the average values in a particular array direction (assuming vertical direction, if you think of a 3D array as a 3D cube) of a certain "bin"...
so I was trying to loop through the "bins" b == 1, b == 2 etc,  sampling the float where that condition is met but being null elsewhere so I can take the average, and then recombine into one array at the end of the loop....
Not sure if I'm making myself understood. I'm using the np.where and using the indexing as I keep getting errors when I try and do it without although it feels very inefficient.

Comment: `empty` sometimes fills the array with 0's; it's undefined what the contents of an `empty()` array is, so 0 is perfectly valid. Try this: `d = np.nan * np.empty((71, 71, 166))`.

Comment: There are a number of ways to effect some sort of "null behavior", so it's important to consider why you want null values in the first place and how you want them to behave with other functions. For an in-depth discussion, see [here](http://www.numpy.org/NA-overview.html).

Comment: THanks Joe,  that's useful. I'm trying to replicate results from an internal program calculator where nulls behave in a very specific way into python and I think I'm projecting ways of doing things in one into the other  - without prior Python knowledge I'm mimicking what I did before instead of making use of more efficient algorithms in Python....

Answer (score 11):

Consider this example:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.random((4,3))
mask = np.random.random_integers(0,1,(4,3))
data[mask==0] = np.NaN
```

The data will be set to `nan` wherever the `mask` is 0. You can use any kind of condition you want, of course, or do something different for different values in b.

To erase everything except a specific bin, try the following:

```
c[b!=1] = np.NaN
```

So, to make a copy of everything in a specific bin:

```
a = np.copy(c)
a[b!=1] == np.NaN
```

To get the average of everything in a bin:

```
np.mean(c[b==1])
```

So perhaps this might do what you want (where bins is a list of bin values):

```
a = np.empty(c.shape)
a[b==0] = np.NaN
for bin in bins:
    a[b==bin] = np.mean(c[b==bin])
```

Comment: would that give me a new array with the value of c where the b condition (==1 or other values in future loops) is met, and empty/null values where it isn't?   to me that looks like I will overwrite c, with all values where b == 1 set to null... sorry, very new to this!

Comment: Was just realizing that might be an issue, and preemptively made an edit!

Answer (score 4):

`np.empty` sometimes fills the array with 0's; it's undefined what the contents of an `empty()` array is, so 0 is perfectly valid. For example, try this instead:

```
d = np.nan * np.empty((71, 71, 166)).
```

But consider using numpy's strength, and don't iterate over the array:

```
a = np.where(b, c, d)
```

(since `b` is 0 or 1, I've excluded the explicit comparison `b == 1`.)

You may even want to consider using a [masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_where.html) instead:

```
a = np.ma.masked_where(b, c)
```

which seems to make more sense with respect to your question: "how do I null certain values in a numpy array based on a condition" (replace null with mask and you're done).

Comment: thanks. I might have over simplified my question. b will eventually have more values in it and I will loop through the values so I will check b == 1, b ==2 etc... I can then take the average of the remaining values in a...

Comment: @idem: Can you add your full question to your current one (don't overwrite the old one, just add the complete question below). It may be just as a simple to do this for your actual question.

Comment: I'd use `fill` instead of multiplication. `d = np.empty(shape)` and then `d.fill(np.nan)`. That seems more clear to me.