# I want to add triplets inside a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I have a numpy 2D array like this one `[[[1,1,1],[5,7,3]],[[1,4,5],[8,3,9]]]`
and I would like to add a triplet `[0,0,0]` to only one of my columns.

I tried the function `np.append` this way:

```
np.append(myArray, [[0,0,0]], axis=0)
```

but it gave me the error:

```
all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions.
```

So I then tried:

```
myArray[0]=np.append(myArray[0], [[0,0,0]], axis=0)
```

to get the column I want, but I got the error:

```
could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (2,3).
```

Is there any way to add my triplets to only one column of `myArray`?

Comment: Is your original data structure a Python list of two Numpy arrays? The error you're getting suggests that you're actually using a 3D array to contain everything. What does `myArray.ndim` return? If it returns 3, that's likely the case and you should use an outer list instead to contain the 2 inner 2D arrays. However, if `myArray` already is a list, it should produce an error, which is fine.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then no. You can't have one "column" (not sure which dimension you mean by this since you had a 3D array - the second?) be longer than the other. You can use a list of lists instead of an array if unequal lengths is really important. How would you use a jagged array that wouldn't work with a normal one? EDIT - I'm actually also confused about the dimensionality of the array / whether lists are involved

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, I finally find a solution. I just made lists of lists, It seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

The nested lists or 2d arrays have to be rectangular in shape. That means all rows have same columns and all columns have same rows. You can see this:
[setting null values in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27527947/11212208) to add null values to your array