# numpy - what is the definition of null value or null column?

Tags: numpy, null

## Question

There are references of `null` such as null value or null column, but what is `null` in numpy? Is it the same with numpy.NaN or something else? Is `null column` a column which all values are NaN or one of the values is NaN?

- [setting null values in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27527947/setting-null-values-in-a-numpy-array)
- [100 numpy exercises - 60. How to tell if a given 2D array has null columns?](https://github.com/rougier/numpy-100/blob/master/100_Numpy_exercises_with_solutions.md#60-how-to-tell-if-a-given-2d-array-has-null-columns-)

Or is it the same with None?

```
a = np.array([
    ("one", "first"),
    (None, "fourth")
])
----
array([['one', 'first'],
       [None, 'fourth']], dtype=object)
```

If I follow the answer of [60. How to tell if a given 2D array has null columns?](https://github.com/rougier/numpy-100/blob/master/100_Numpy_exercises_with_solutions.md#60-how-to-tell-if-a-given-2d-array-has-null-columns-), np.zeros() includes null value as it results in True (there is null column). Then null is also zero in numpy?

```
a = np.zeros((3,3))
print((~a.any(axis=0)).any())
---
True
```

Comment: `null` really doesn't a meaning in `numpy`, and not even in Python.  Python has a `None` object, and float numpy arrays may contain `np.nan` values.  That sample code tests for 0s.  That may be useful, but I wouldn't call that a `null` column.

Answer (score 2):

Let me start by describing each type -
`np.NaN` dtype - This is a float type class. Numpy follows IEEE 754 standards to represent their numbers. According to this document. NaN is an undefined number. For example, `log(-1), sqrt(-1), 0*inf, 0/0` All these belong to the category of not a number. These operations will return a NaN.

```
>>> np.log(-1)
nan
>>> np.sqrt(-1)
nan
>>> 0*np.inf
nan
```

NaN does not mean `inf` or 0. Expressing any digit beyond the capacity of the Numpy array leads to the following behavior.

```
>>> x = np.array([1e-50], dtype=np.float32)
>>> x
array([0.], dtype=float32)
>>> x = np.array([1e50], dtype=np.float32)
>>> x
array([inf], dtype=float32)
>>> np.inf == np.NaN
False
>>> 0.0 == np.NaN
False
```

Now, what is the difference between `None` and `np.NaN`.
In Python `None` is a keyword. It has its own type `NoneType`.
It can be thought of as the `null` of Python. In other languages, we use 0 or some other number to represent `null`. In python we do not do so, we use an entirely new data type called `NoneType`. By default `None` is "falsy" which means evaluating `if not None` returns `True`. Just like an empty list, empty dictionary, empty string, 0.

```
>>> not None
True
>>> not []
True
>>> not 0
True
```

As I see your question, None seems like a good choice but beware that you have to keep your `dtype` as object. This is because you have two different types `string` and `Nonetype` inside the same array. These 2 types are child of the parent class `object` that you have defined in your array. This will have memory overheads. Having the same data type helps NumPy allocate memory efficiently, improve execution speed. Therefore, if you define an array like `np.empty([])` it populates it with a float value 0. Which functions like a `null` value. Look at the following example -

```
>>> np.empty((1,2), dtype=object)
array([[None, None]], dtype=object) 
>>> np.empty((1,2), dtype=np.float32)
array([[1.60e-43, 1.54e-43]], dtype=float32) # this is 0,0
```

References -

- [IEEE 754 wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)
- [Numpy NaN](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/misc.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you put a link to "According to this document"?

Comment: There you go -[IEEE 754 wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), [Numpy NaN](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/misc.html) . If you like this answer, please consider marking this as the right answer.

Comment: Thanks Shubham Bhardwaj. Really appreciate answering and hope you kindly understand. I think the answer is that from hpaulj in the comment to the question. "There is no such thing null in numpy. The word null is mis-used sometime as NaN or zero". Hence I believe we should not use "null" in Python nor Numpy.

Comment: But the answer is informative and helpful.

Comment: While I have upvoted the answer, one strong point needs to come out clearly - np.empty for a float will return any arbit value. See the API definition: "returns array of uninitialized (arbitrary) data of the given shape, dtype, and order" and it is recommended to use it with caution. With float types, np.zeroes are usually much better. Of course with objects you are guaranteed that they will be initialized to None. Hence the upvote as it perfectly fits into what the OP is asking